# Can you stretch a button in Interface builder in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

I understood you can stretch a button in certain areas so that it may retain a good aspect and not look deformed, in Interface builder Xcode 4 . Is this true and if so, how can you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Dragging to stretch a button in interface builder does not make it deformed. It automatically retains good aspect and does not look pixelated or scaled up. Just grabbing the corners and dragging should do the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: lets say i have a button of 100x30 . If i would like to stretch only the middle and not stretch the first and last 10 pixels of the width, can i do so ?

Comment: The only way you can do that is if you use a photo editor like photoshop. You will need to select the inside part of the image and then stretch it. You can use many alternatives to photoshop too, just google it. There's tons of good ones. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong. You can do it using code with UIButton's `setBackgroundImage:stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth`.

Answer (score 6):

The X and Y values seem to be the positions for the stretch starting point, relative to the entire width and height of the image, i.e. 0.5 would mean a point in the middle of the image.

Same thing for the Width and Height: sizes for the stretchable area, relative to the image size, i.e. setting it to a value of 1 / imageWidth would mean the stretchable area is 1 pixel wide. The strange thing is 0 also work fine for the blue pill button (could be for convenience reasons?).

Below, view modes are set to "Scale to Fill". The images are stretchable images from  https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor.

### [image]

This answer was inspired by http://www.slideshare.net/mystcolor/stretchable-images-in-uiimageview-using-ib-only